# Incorrect hash value when using Horner's Rule after the first call

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, hashtable

I am writing my own implementation of a HashMap, and I am using Horner's Rule for the hashing algorithm. I have my hashing algorithm here

```
    public int hashCode(K key) {
        int rank = 0;
        int hashCode = 0;
        char[] charArr = ((String) key).toCharArray();
                
        int exponent = (5 * (charArr.length - 1)) - 5;
    
        for(int i = 0; i <= charArr.length - 1; i++) {
            if(exponent >= 0) {
                rank = ((int) charArr[i] - 'A') + 1;
                hashCode += rank * (32 << exponent);
                exponent -= 5;
            }
            else{
                rank = ((int) charArr[i] - 'A') + 1;
                hashCode += rank * (32 >> 5);
            }
        }
        return hashCode;
    }
```

Which if given `String userStr = "tea"` it will produce 20,641 as the hash value to start. I only know this because of print statements for troubleshooting within my methods which I took out. Although, when I go to receive the hash value later within my driver, I get 54,465 as the value. This is not double 20,641, so it is not just running twice. I have no idea why this is like that. I attached my retrieve method within the `HashTable class`, along with the part of the driver that is experiencing the issue. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

```
    public V tableRetrieve(K searchKey) {
        if(!this.tableIsEmpty()) {
            int index = hashCode(searchKey) % table.length;
            ChainNode<K, V> currNode = table[index]; //getting the node based off the index 
            while(currNode != null) {
                if(currNode.getKey().equals(searchKey)) {
                    return currNode.getValue();  //found match return currNode value
                }
                else {
                    currNode = currNode.getNext(); //go onto next node within linked list
                }
            }
        }
        return null; //if nothing was found return null
    }
```

```
    public static void retrieveHashCode(HashTable<String, Integer> myTable) {
        try {
            String key;
            System.out.print("Please enter a string key to retrieve the hashcode of it from the table\n> ");
            key = input.readLine();
            if(myTable.tableRetrieve(key.toUpperCase()) != null) {
                System.out.println("The hash code of " + key + " is " + myTable.hashCode(key) + ".");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("The key " + key + " is not present within the table.");
            }
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a string value.");
        }
        catch(IOException e1) {
            System.out.println(e1.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is wrong: `key.toUpperCase()`. Or, at least, it's not consistent with `myTable.hashCode(key)`. Use either `.toUpperCase()` in both statements or leave `key` as is

Comment: @fps the key.toUpperCase() is there because I decided to store all keys in uppercase. I even went and took it out to see if it would work correctly without it but it does not. Thank you though  Edit: checking again, did not see the whole comment. My apologies

Comment: You should also show the code when you're inserting in the table

Comment: You were very correct with the toUpperCase() comment, my apologies for saying you were not. Thank you. I knew it was a little discrepancy within the code.

Comment: Great I could help you!

Comment: Where do you store the key (after upper casing it) in the table?